# Changing the Shliach Tzibbur in the middle of a prayer service

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader

On many occasions in Israel one person will lead pseukei d'zimrah but then step down to allow someone else to lead prayers; presumably because they simply don't want to continue. But often, because there may have been a delay in starting, someone will agree to 'get the service going' but then step down before Barechu.

I have davened with a particular chassidic group where the Rebbe was renowned for a long amidah. The Rebbe led maariv at the start, but someone else continued as shliach tzibbur after the personal amidah (i.e. said kaddish, then aleinu, etc.) because the Rebbe takes much longer than everyone else.

Question: Is it better to keep one shliach tzibbur for the whole of the service, or is it ok to change in the middle? If its ok to change, then at what point can this be done and for what reasons?

Comment: Was it weekday or Shabbos maariv?  There's potentially a difference because of מגן אבות.  It sounds like weekday but might be better to clarify explicitly.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56417/origin-of-custom-to-switch-shliach-tzibur-in-shacharit?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment149467_56417  possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22143/759

Comment: I think O.C. mentions that it is OK to change just before the 2nd Ashrei. Mishnah Brachot, I think implies that there is a change before Hallel, when it is said. I have to hunt for other locations. My sense is that one should stick with one chazzan the entire time, when possible. I think a shul / minyan should have one shaliach. That seemed to be the historical sense of having the shaliach to begin with. Remember that not everyone knew tefilla and there were no "formal" siddurim around. That's the premise for Chazarat Hashat"z.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57871/5275 regarding switching shat"z at Ashrei. I'm uncertain why it has become common to switch before Yishtabach. I don't have access to beureihatefilah, as I think there is an article there discussing this.

Comment: Part of the answer i found here: http://www.ttidbits.com/1053/1253veb.pdf